# lxml: Converting XML to HTML through XSLT and get HtmlElements

Tags: python, html, xml, xslt, lxml

I have data that comes as an XML file. I have also been provided an XSLT to transform the XML to HTML. I can use lxml to perform the conversion, however, I want to alter some of the HTML tags after the transformation. How do I convert this new etree into HtmlElements so that I can specifically use certain methods like .cssselect() and so on.

Comment: is not it easier to change xslt code?

Comment: No. I want to get the filenames from the newly created <img> tags so that I can Base64encode them into the new html file. Stuff like that.

Comment: Hi, could you perhaps send me the code you use to transform the xml and xslt to html? I cant find anything on the net.

Comment: http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt

Comment: @OozeMeister : `I have also been provided an XSLT to transform the XML to HTML`.    Can you please share the python code you used for this.

Comment: @NevinRaj, there's a simple example in lxml's documentation:
http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> import lxml.html
>>>
>>> xmlstring = '''\
... <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
... <root><a class="here">link1</a><a class="there">link2</a></root>
... '''
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmlstring)
>>> root.cssselect('a.here')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'cssselect'
```

`lxml.etree.tostring(root)` -> `lxml.html.fromstring(..)`

```py
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring(lxml.etree.tostring(root))
>>> root.cssselect('a.here')
[<Element a at 0x2989308>]
```

Get XML output:

```py
>>> print lxml.etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True)
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<root><a class="here">link1</a><a class="there">link2</a></root>
```